# Safari sends fetch ajax requests on url bar autofilled

Tags: ajax, safari, fetch

my client side react app is running on http://localhost:3000 and my node js server is running on http://localhost:8080. When client url is loaded, it sends GET /auth/user 304 0.494 ms - - fetch ajax request to load user(on react componentDidMount function). Problem is, when typing 'l' on Safari browser and url is autofilled with 'http://localhost:3000', it is confirmed that my server get the same request as GET /auth/user, before I even press enter key and before the client page is loaded. In Chrome it doesn't. Why Safari browser sends ajax request when user didn't visit the page and just typed part of its url? Is it a designed behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As a result of tracking the reason for 6 hours. I figured out Safari implements cached ajax request differently from other web browsers. When Safari has client url data which has records of requesting ajax to external api, Safari sends the same ajax request just before user visits the client url page(when url is being typed and auto-suggested) to check if the response is 200(different) or 304(same). If the response is 304(same) and client page is loaded actually, Safari doesn't send ajax request again. This can be very annoying in the user login process, because the user data is loaded before actual authentication process is complete(user data response is 304), so client app remains unauthenticated when browser is authenticated. The solution I landed was adding an extra query parameter when fetching user data( '${root}/auth/user?' + 'nocache= new Date.getTime()' ) to prevent Caching AJAX in Safari browser. Hope it helps someone who faces the same problem.